# Fix image rotation in PHP

Tags: php, image, image-rotation

I am passing a user selected image to the php file below.  Some of the images are auto rotating when user selects.  In particular, rotating counter clockwise 90 degrees.  I want a php function that can check rotation and fix before I move it.  Pics may be jpeg or gif or png.  But if I can just get a fix for jpeg, I would be happy.

```
    <?php
$itemname = $_REQUEST["Item_Name"];
$itemdescription = $_REQUEST["Item_Description"];
$useremail = $_REQUEST["User_Email"];
$itemimage = $_FILES['Item_Image']['tmp_name'];

if(isset($_FILES['Item_Image']) && $_FILES['Item_Image']['name']!=""){
    $image_name= $_FILES['Item_Image']['name'];
    if($image_name=="IMG/"){
    $image_path = "http://mywebsite.com/PICS/square-image.png";
    }
    else
    {
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Item_Image']['tmp_name'], "PICS/$image_name");
    $image_path = "http://mywebsite.com/PICS/" .$image_name;
    }
}

?>
```

What can I do before move_uploaded_file that will rotate the image correctly?

Comment: are there mobile devices involved at all that you are aware of?

Comment: more than likely.  it is doing it on my Mac.  the pic I took is from my iPhone but I am loading it to the site through my Mac computer

Comment: any automatic rotation requires the image to have that information i.e. from the camera in its EXIF data... if you can use the imagick module from PECL, [this example code from PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation.php#111448) may help you...

Comment: https://obrienmedia.co.uk/blog/fixing-photo-orientation-on-images-uploaded-via-php-from-ios-devices